# Accessing MySQL database in node.js - internal assertion fails

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to MySQL database from node.js using [db-mysql](https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql/) library. Everything works great with example code, but now I'm trying to write a simple ORM.

This is my code:

```js
require.paths.unshift('/usr/lib/node_modules'); // default require.paths doesn't include this

function Model() {
  this.database = null;
}

Model.prototype.getDB = function(callback) {
  if (this.database != null)
    callback(this.database);
  else {
    console.log("Connecting to database...");
    this.database = require("db-mysql").Database({
      "hostname" : "localhost",
      "user"     : "root",
      "password" : "pass",
      "database" : "miku",
    }).on("ready", function() {
      console.log("Database ready, saving for further use.");
      this.database = this; 
      callback(this); 
    });
  }
}

exports.Model = Model;
```

And simple code I use for testing:

```js
orm = require('./orm');
model = new orm.Model();
model.getDB(function (db) { console.log("callback'd"); });
```

It looks fine (at least for me), however node.js fails with internal assertion:

```
Connecting to database...
node: /usr/include/node/node_object_wrap.h:61: void node::ObjectWrap::Wrap(v8::Handle<v8::Object>): Assertion `handle->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.
Przerwane (core dumped)
```

After further investigation, if fails before/during creating Database object. I have no idea why this happens. I first though that it's because I was using git node.js version, but it fails with current release (v0.4.7) as well.

I'm trying to track down this issue in node.js code, with no success at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, it was me to fail hard. It seems that having Python background is undesired in JavaScript world ;).

Database initialization should look like:

```
db = require("db-mysql");
new db.Database({
  "hostname" : "localhost",
  "user"     : "root",
  "password" : "pass",
  "database" : "miku",
}).on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Database ready, saving for further use.");
  this.database = this; 
  callback(this); 
}).connect();
```

So, I basically forgot to call `new` and `connect()`.

Comment: Another small issue: trailing commas in object initializers (as in '"database" : "miku",})' are "officially" illegal though some interpreters let them slide. Better not to use them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that! JavaScript seems a bit odd here, many languages allow them (and I've seen many style guidelines which recommended them).

Comment: When we finally get to Javascript2, they will be allowed but for example, saying '[1,2,].length === 3' is true in many flavors of IE including IE8. See http://ejohn.org/blog/bug-fixes-in-javascript-2/